# How does Intel TBB's scalable_allocator work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, malloc, tbb

What does the `tbb::scalable_allocator` in Intel Threading Building Blocks actually do under the hood ?

It can certainly be effective.  I've just used it to take 25% off an apps' execution time (and see an increase in CPU utilization from ~200% to 350% on a 4-core system) by changing a single `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<T,tbb::scalable_allocator<T> >`.  On the other hand in another app I've seen it double an already large memory consumption and send things to swap city.

Intel's own documentation doesn't give a lot away (e.g a short section at the end of this  [FAQ](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_TBB)).  Can anyone tell me what tricks it uses before I go and dig into its code myself ?

**UPDATE**: Just using TBB 3.0 for the first time, and seen my best speedup from scalable_allocator yet.  Changing a single `vector<int>` to a `vector<int,scalable_allocator<int> >` reduced the runtime of something from 85s to 35s (Debian Lenny, Core2, with TBB 3.0 from testing).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a good paper on the allocator: [The Foundations for Scalable Multi-core Software in Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/research/2007-vol11-iss-4-intel-technology-journal.pdf)

My limited experience: I overloaded the global new/delete with the tbb::scalable_allocator for my AI application. But there was little change in the time profile. I didn't compare the memory usage though.

Comment: Thanks!  Article contains exactly the sort of information I was looking for.

Comment: The original link is now defunct, but CiteSeer has the PDF: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.71.8289

Comment: To add a datapoint: in my particular app, allocator contention halted speedup at around 15 threads, past that it would kill all speedup and by 40 it would be much slower than single-thread. With `scalable_allocator` used in the inner per-thread kernels the bottleneck disappeared and expected scaling came back. (machine has 40 physical cores).

Answer (score 3):

The solution you mentioned is optimized for Intel CPUs. It incorporates specific CPU mechanisms to improve performance.

Sometime ago I found another very useful solution: [Fast C++11 allocator for STL containers](https://github.com/moya-lang/Allocator). It slightly speeds up STL containers on VS2017 (~5x) as well as on GCC (~7x). It uses memory pool for elements allocation which makes it extremely effective for all platofrms.