# What is the difference between memory allocation through new and allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, allocator

What is the difference between memory allocation through `new`/`malloc` and `allocator`?

Why would we ever need a separate memory allocator for vector if we have the options of `new` and `malloc`?

Comment: 1 google search: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_malloc_and_new_other_than_syntax

Comment: Floris Velleman,I was not looking for difference between new and delete.

Comment: Hmm. I don’t see how the “duplicate” answers this specific question. Well, maybe partly (“allocators are pluggable”) but it doesn’t address the specific question about distinguishing between allocation and construction. I’m also not sure of the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman: and how do you propose that the OP filters out all the garbage on Google from the actual correct information? SO is intended as a source for good, reliable answers to programming questions. Google is not. Therefore, you are wasting your own and everyone elses time by telling people who ask questions on SO to google it instead. The purpose of SO is that *if* you Google, a SO answer should be the #1 result.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, I think that `new` and `malloc` are different and `allocator` provides different functions. `malloc` returns non-initialized data, and `calloc` returns *zero*-ed data. But `new` would call the constructor if you are creating an instance of some class ( not `int`, `bool` these *primitive* types, which, by the way, can be initialized as well ). `delete` would call the destructor, while `free` doesn't.

As for `allocator`, it provides a layer of abstraction for the user. `allocator` can return constructed object, non-initialized memory space, or destroy a object or release the space. STL containers use `allocator`  to get memory space and create object.

But note that as custom `allocator` is possible, an `allocator` does not necessarily manage memory like `new`/`delete`. It can create a large chunk of memory then do some *allocation cache*. It can return memory address in areas mapped to files on disk so that the internal data goes into the filesystem as it's modified by the upper layer, *container*. Also it can call `new` to get memory. In this way, `allocator` enables user to build containers that lie in specific areas of the memory. So, with `allocator`s, the internal logic of containers are separated from the way memory storage is managed.

Actually you can write a class derived from `std::allocator` to implement every feature mentioned above.

---

you might want to read [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-what-are-allocato/184403759) for a more detailed discussion on `allocator`s.

Answer (score 2):

When you use new or malloc, the memory management is hard-wired to the corresponding functions in the runtime of your compiler. In contrast, when an allocator is used, memory management is  delegated to the allocator, which is exchangeable. This allows you to alter the memory managing functions used.

There are some good reasons to have this extra level of abstraction and control. For example see: 
[Compelling examples of custom C++ STL allocators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826569/compelling-examples-of-custom-c-stl-allocators).

Answer (score 0):

In the `allocator` class there is an `allocate()` which takes two parameters as follows:

```
pointer allocate (size_type n, allocator<void>::const_pointer hint=0);
```

According to the reference [of allocate()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/) the hint parameter can be used to improve performance by mentioning that you need to allocate a new block of memory adjacent to the one specified. So i believe using the hint you can assign blocks such that they are sequential like in case of an array.

Answer (score 0):

An allocator is a memory manager. STL containers for instance, provide default allocators, but one can customize them as explain in this article (a tutorial for STL allocators): http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079/Allocators-STL.htm.