# How to dynamically allocate a 2D std::array in C++ or why I should not use it?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I want to malloc an array in my code, and its size should be defined at runtime.

I tried like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main(){
    int M=4,N=3,P=5;
    M=N+P;
    std::array<std::array<double,M>,N> arr;
}
```

But MSVC told me:

```
a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument
```

I don't find the answer to this in stackoverflow.(The existing question seem not to solve my problem...)

How to dynamically allocate a 2D std::array in C++?

I know I could use `std::vector` to solve this. But the vector memory size needs to be organized by myself and this would be used many times in my project. And I want to use C++ type code rather than C type...Maybe there is a method to turn a 2D array in C type to `std::array`, but I can't find it by Google...

So I ask this question...

I mean the M and N should be got dynamically(not changed,but I can only know it in runtime...),like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a=3;
    int b=4;
    int rowCount=a+b;
    int colCout=b-a;
    int** a = new int*[rowCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = new int[colCount];
    }
}
```

I know where is my mistake. I fell into a logical question...  If I don't use push_back,the vector works well. If I use it, the array doesn't work, too.

I think the capcity of vector is bigger than its size, I want to avoid this. But another question: [How to limit the capacity of std::vector to the number of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432259/how-to-limit-the-capacity-of-stdvector-to-the-number-of-element) show I should use my allocator or `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` to avoid it...(There is no guarantee in C++17 if you use `reserve(n)`)

Comment: You want a std::vector. std::array is a fixed size at compile time.

Comment: If you want to use C++ type code instead of C code for handling containers whose size isn't known until run time, you want to use std::vector. I don't understand the question.

Comment: The `std::vector` is the right solution. *"But the vector memory size need to organize by myself"* I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: ***I mean the M and N should be got dynamically(not changed,but I can only know it in runtime...)*** Then you will need a std::vector and not std::array.

Comment: Maybe you need to show why you think a std::vector won't work for your problem. I think this is a bit of a XY problem.

Comment: @drescherjm Because the vector memory size is bigger than the same array if I don‘t control by myself, I think I should get it in constructor...

Comment: Maybe you want to allocate a 1D vector and use a matrix class

Comment: @LearningLin that makes no sense. `std::vector` will get you exactly the memory you need.

Comment: @drescherjm I will get vector.capacity() in the "fine_vector" constructor

Comment: @LearningLin what? That makes no sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you are right. I mean if I don't use push_back, the memory size should be I want. Thank you.

Comment: there's a constructor of `std::vector` with which you can specify the exact size, see (3) in the list at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) - (edit also [mentioned in answer by Marcus Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71817560) I just saw)

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, this is a X-Y problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dynamically allocated array container in C++ is `std::vector`. `std::array` is for specifically *compile-time fixed-length* arrays.

https://cppreference.com is your friend!

> But the vector memory size needs to be organized by myself

Not quite sure what you mean with that, but you specify the size of your `std::vector` using  the constructor.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(N);
```

If you need some special allocator (not just `new`/`malloc`), then you can also specify a custom allocator.

Your whole program that you propose is not good C++. A C++ solution would look like:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    unsigned int rowCount = a + b;
    unsigned int colCount = b - a;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(rowCount);
    for (auto& row : matrix) {
        row.resize(colCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get the point. I guess I should define a new type for it.

Comment: @LearningLin I don't think that was the point

Comment: ...What? How is that your takeaway from this?

Comment: @LearningLin no, that was not the point, at all. You don't need a new type. The existing `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` simply works.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you are right. I mean if I don't use push_back, the memory size should be I want. Thank you

Comment: Is my answer right? I mean the capacity of vector may be bigger than vector. And I want to avoid it. In C++17, the other question show there is no method unless I use my allocator. Does it exit in C++20?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking me here. But if something existed in C++17, it will still exist in C++20. Also, you seem to think that overallocation is really bad, but it's not. If the memory pages allocated to the vector are not touched, they don't use physical memory. So, the most you're wasting could be a little less than 4 kB in RAM. Which you would also be wasting with `new` or `malloc`, you just don't notice.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array`, like an actual array in C++, requires a constant size. It's what gives it any advantage at all over `std::vector`.

For a technical explanation as to how that requirement is implemented, remember that template parameters are required to be compile-time constants (since it changes how the code is generated, again at compile-time).

Anyway, you want to use `std::vector` here. If you know the size you want, give it as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Ok, I get the point. I guess I should define a new type for it.

Comment: @LearningLin not at all what Blindy said. You must have misunderstood!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I know where I misunderstood, thank you.