# Is there any performance comparison between TBB::scalable_allocator, tcmalloc and jemalloc?

Tags: multithreading, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, tbb

I want to use a memory allocator in multithreading enviroment and each thread eats a lot of memory. Which should I choose? Is there any performance between these allocators? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try them all in your particular app?

Comment: It depends a lot on the details.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657783/how-does-intel-tbbs-scalable-allocator-work for a couple of data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'I want to use a memory allocator in multithreading enviroment and each thread eats a lot of memory.' - why?  What for?

'Which should I choose?' - two possibilities:

1) Profile/analyze your application and match the memory requirement charateristics again the specs for each of the allocators.

2) Test you app with each allocator to find out empirically which matches your application best.

'Is there any performance between these allocators?' - I guess you mean 'performance difference'.  I'm almost 100% sure that there is a difference, yes.